Getting error open_basedir restriction in effect when uploading file in filament
Using fillament tryin to upload file   /livewire/upload-file
succesfully uploaded file in storage app public liveware-tmp but then liveware/update getting 500  is_file(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/tmp/phpO5HriX) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/www-root/data:.) public has 755 permission photo in browser opening but why here this error

